# Is that possible to group result on 3 months period basis?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to group results by 3 months period starting by the current month as shown below:

```
row1      15 -- This should contain November, September and October
row2      25 -- This should contain August, July and June
row3      5  -- This should contain May, April and March
row4      2  -- This is should contain February and Janvier
```

I have no idea about how to accomplish this. Any help please?

So far I can group by month:

```
SELECT MONTH(date), MONTHNAME(date) as month, COUNT(*) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE MONTH(date) < NOW()  
GROUP BY MONTH(date) 
ORDER BY MONTH(date) DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the following I am assuming you already have a numbers table, If you don't have a numbers table, then I'd recommend you make one then, but if you don't want to then you can [create a number list on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql)

With this numbers table you can then define your quarters:

```
SELECT  DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL -Number - 1 QUARTER) AS QuarterStart,
        DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL -Number QUARTER) AS QuarterEnd
FROM    Numbers
```

This gives (When run at the time of answering in November 2013):

```
QUARTERSTART    QUARTEREND
2013-09-01      2013-12-01
2013-06-01      2013-09-01
2013-03-01      2013-06-01
```

If the same query was run next month the result would be:

```
QUARTERSTART    QUARTEREND
2013-10-01      2014-01-01
2013-07-01      2013-10-01
2013-04-01      2013-07-01
```

You can then join your table data to this:

```
SELECT  DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL -n.Number - 1 QUARTER) AS QuarterStart,
        DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL -n.Number QUARTER), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS QuarterEnd,
        COUNT(t.ID) AS `Count`
FROM    Numbers n
        INNER JOIN Table_Name t
            ON t.DateField >= DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL -n.Number - 1 QUARTER)
            AND t.DateField < DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL -n.Number QUARTER)
GROUP BY n.Number;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/149e6/2)**

*N.B. In the select I have deducted one day from the quarter end field as visually the last day of the quarter appears more relevant, but for the join I have kept it as the first day of the next quarter, but used the less than operator*

Of course if you also want to count empty quarters you can change the join to a `LEFT JOIN`, but you will probably then want to limit the number of rows you are returning by adding a Where clause.